# Conditional indexing a matrix in Stan

Tags: indexing, vectorization, stan

I have the following code that correctly specifies the model I'm thinking of:

```
for (iT in 1:T)
  for (iN in 1:N)
    if (!is_inf(y[iT,iN]))
      y[iT,iN] ~ normal(Gamma[iN] * F[iT], sigma[iT]);
```

However, this seems somewhat slow compared to a vectorized version that I have without the check on whether `y` is inf or not (which I am using to represent missing values).

I would like to be able to do something like

```
for (iT in 1:T) {
  isObserved = !is_inf(y[iT,]);
  y[iT,isObserved] ~ normal(Gamma[isObserved ] * F[iT], sigma[iT]);
}
```

But it appears that logical indexing like this is not supported.

Questions:

1. Is there a syntax for logical indexing that I've missed?
2. Is there another way that I can vectorize this code to improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `transformed data` block to create a vector with all the non-missing values of `y`, and then access the appropriate parameters in the model with multiple indexing.  The advantage of this approach is that those computations over your data happen only once.  Here's an example of how that could work; for convenience, I also added a user-defined function to compute how many non-missing values we have.  (I'm assuming that any cell in `y` could be missing - but if there are patterns, such as whole rows or columns missing, this could be simplified.)

```
functions {
  int count_non_missing_values(matrix y) {
    int nm = 0;
    for(i in 1:rows(y)) {
      for(j in 1:cols(y)) {
        if(!is_inf(y[i,j])) {
          nm += 1;
        }
      }
    }
    return(nm);
  }
}

data {
  int T;
  int N;
  matrix[T,N] y;
}

transformed data {
  vector[count_non_missing_values(y)] flat_ys;
  int flat_Ts[count_non_missing_values(y)];
  int flat_Ns[count_non_missing_values(y)];
  {
    int ind = 1;
    for(iT in 1:T) {
      for(iN in 1:N) {
        if(!is_inf(y[iT,iN])) {
          flat_ys[ind] = y[iT,iN];
          flat_Ts[ind] = iT;
          flat_Ns[ind] = iN;
          ind += 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

parameters {
  vector[T] F;
  vector<lower=0>[T] sigma;
  vector[N] Gamma;
}

model {
  flat_ys ~ normal(Gamma[flat_Ns] .* F[flat_Ts], sigma[flat_Ts]);
}
```